# react-boilerplate rootSaga

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

In my previous project, there was a rootSaga.js in the src directory, the code is as follows:

```
import { all, fork } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { cubeSagas } from 'cubeBoco'

export default function* root() {
   yield all(
     cueSagas.map(saga => fork(saga))
   )
}
```

How can I achieve it, in the react-boilerplate(https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could add it to your App/index.js in the same way as the rest of the application

```
import { compose } from 'redux';
import injectSaga from 'utils/injectSaga';
import saga from './saga';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
      </Switch>
      <GlobalStyle />
    </div>
  );
}
const withSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'global', saga });

export default compose(withSaga)(App);
```

Answer (score 1):

With the new `redux-hooks` you have to:
1) Add the reducer in global `reducer.js` file:

```
export default function createReducer(
  injectedReducers = {},
) {
  const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    global: globalReducer,
    router: connectRouter(history),
    ...injectedReducers,
  });

  return rootReducer;
}
```

2) Import `saga.js`and `reducer.js` from global reducer and give `key`the same name as the reducers name in global `reducer.js`:

```
import { useInjectReducer } from 'utils/injectReducer';
import { useInjectSaga } from 'utils/injectSaga';
import reducer from '../global/reducer';
import saga from '../global/sagas';
const key = 'global';
```

3) Inject it in your function component:

```
  useInjectReducer({ key, reducer });
  useInjectSaga({ key, saga });
```

That works for me. Can use it in several routes, i.e. different pages that use same global saga and reducer.
Best Regards.

Comment: Its long time. But let me ask, `useInjectReducer({ key, reducer });`
here, reducer is combineReducer so, how one "key" is accessed to rootReducer. Is it just one Reducer key  (i.e. SliceKey) ?

Comment: @dsi Was a long time ago I checked, you can see the new version code here https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/v5-with-cra/src/app/containers/GithubRepoForm/index.tsx